# Getting data from a website repeatedly inside a service (android)

Tags: android, service

I was writing an app that should get data from a website every 15 minutes (in the code it is 10 seconds just to check if it works easily). I am using a service and handler inside it. The following is my Service class:

getRating() should be called every 10 seconds, I do my calculations inside it using [ION](https://github.com/koush/ion/blob/master/README.md) library, then call the getData method.
getData() is used to get the value of x (it can't be assigned to a global variable because it is in an inner class).

**The problem is that the code after calling method getRating is being executed before the method is finished (I tried showing toasts inside and after the method, the one after is showing first) therefore variable y is not updating correctly.**

My question is why does this happen? and what should i do to correct it?
What i thought about:

- somehow delaying the execution of the code after the method by enough time to finish the method first.
- Or should I use another way of getting the data? another library maybe?

Thank you.

---

```
package com.example.l50.bla;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import com.koushikdutta.async.future.FutureCallback;
import com.koushikdutta.ion.Ion;


public class MyService extends Service {
    Handler mHandler;
    int T;
    void getData(int x)
    {
        T=x;
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mHandler = new Handler();
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
                public void run() {
                getRating();
                int y=T;

                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
            }
        };
        mHandler.postDelayed(r, 10000);
    }
    void getRating() {
        String url ="http://www.somewebsite.com";
        Ion.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(url)
                .asString()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
                        int x;
                        // do some calculations, the result of these calculations is stored in x
                        getData(x);
                });
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Search Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**UPD**: In my case, I can guarantee that the value of x wont be zero, so I can just skip when x is not yet updated, this will solve the problem , but with some delay. How can I do it more efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here:

- Creating a `Handler` in a `Service` is not the same as running in a background thread, off of the main thread of your app.
- Because the `Runnable` is just being re-queued it will only continue to execute as long as the system is not in a low power mode.  As soon as that happens, your `Service` will no longer get execution context and your polling will not work.  Consider using something like `JobScheduler` (requires API 21 or newer) or alarms to handle periodic requests.
- The reason your `Runnable` code after `getRating()` is running is because the ION method being called by `getRating()` is *asynchronous*.  It will properly run on a background thread then call your app back via the provided method once it has finished.  If you are doing something similar in your `getData()` method then you'll likely encounter a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. About the 3rd point, is there a way to delay the code after `getRating()` until the ION method is finished?

Comment: Don't delay, take your action in the callback.